# What is the name of this plant, is it edible, and how can I care for it?

Tags: identification, plant-health, herbs, edible

[image: THE PLANT WAS IN A GARDEN AND SAID CUBAN CUMIN. BUT I AFRAID OF EATING IT]

I took a little bunch, but it in water and planted it when I saw the roots. 
the original plant was low, close to the floor. I kind of like it going up. This plant smells really nice. It's super resilient. I haven't take care of it at all. It has survived the sun of Miami with poor water, and the rainy season. It is the only warrior that has survived with me for 3 years. 'Cuban Cumin' was in the garden sign. Is that what this is?

I want to know if is edible. I have been very nice to it lately and want to know more about the benefits of this plant.

Comment: Could you please describe it a bit more? Is there a specific smell, for example?

Answer (score 2):

I did some research with the phrase "Cuban Cumin" you gave in your post:

Have you checked  [Plectranthus amboinicus](http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/1356/)"Cuban Oregano" / "Spanish Thyme" / "Indian Borage"? 
Your plant looks quite similar to this: 
[image: this].

As you told us very little about the characteristics of your plant, you could compare yours with the description at the link abobe.

Comment: it does look like a member of the plectranthus family, but can you add to your answer rather than just linking off site?

Comment: Problem is, OP gave very litte information and my answer just gives the result of some internet search. I'd rather not "identify" something on so little data, especially as I haven't seen /felt/smelled this plant ever. And OP ask's whether the plant is edible - another reason I don't want to expand on it. Feel free to add to mine or write an own answer!